# my rock paper scissors gives me nothing in output (python)

Tags: python, windows, function, random, output

I am new to python and as a practice I'm trying to write a **rock paper scissors** with it.
I triple checked eth but i can't find the problem.
I'm using visual studio code console. the msvcrt is for "getch" and I'm not sure about about the random function syntax

problem: when you give it the input number, It doesn't do or write anything despite the program.
help me pleaaaaase.

```
import random
import msvcrt 
##################################################
player_move = " "
system_move = " "
##################################################
def rand(system_move):
    rn = random.randint(1, 3)
    if rn == 1:
        system_move = "Rock"
    elif rn == 2:
        system_move = "Paper"
    elif rn == 3:
        system_move = "Scissors"
    else:
        rand()
    return system_move
##################################################
print("!!! Rock, Paper, Scissors !!!\n\n\n")
###################################################
def playermove(player_move):
    print("What do you want to go with?\n1-Rock\n2-paper\n3-scissors\n")
    temp = msvcrt.getch()
    if temp == '1' or 1:
        player_move = 'Rock'
    elif temp == '2' or 2:
        player_move = 'Paper'
    elif temp == '3' or 3:
        player_move = 'Scissors'
    else:
        print(f"invalid input {player_move}. Try again\n")
        playermove()
    return player_move
###################################################
pm = ' '
sm = ' '
rand(sm)
playermove(pm)
if pm== 'Scissors':
    if sm == "Scissors":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nIt's a tie!\n")
    elif sm == "Rock":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nSystem won!\n")
    elif sm == "Paper":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nYou won!\n")
    else:
        print("Oops! Something went wrong.\n")
        
elif pm == "Paper":
    if sm == "Scissors":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nSystem won!\n")
    elif sm == "Rock":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nYou won!\n")
    elif sm == "Paper":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nIt's a tie!\n")
    else:
        print("Oops! Something went wrong.\n")
elif pm == "Rock":
    if sm == "Scissors":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nYou won!\n")
    elif sm == "Rock":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nIt's a tie!\n")
    elif sm == "Paper":
        print(f"System move: {sm}\nSystem won!\n")
    else:
        print("Oops! Something went wrong.\n")

print("Press any key to exit...")
xyz = msvcrt.getch()
```

Comment: Why do you not use the `input` function to get input from the user?

Comment: because you'll have to press enter with input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the reason your code doesn't work is because you are not assigning the return value of your functions to any variable. To fix your code you need to do the following:

```
sm = rand(sm)
pm = playermove(pm)
```

In Python, passing an immutable object like string means that you cannot make any changes to it. As you're not using the passed value, your function's signature should actually look like this.

```
def rand()
def playermove()
```

After you do this, you'll see there are other things you need to fix in your code.

Comment: No problem. If the solution helped you, mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Just replace snake, water, gun by rock, paper, scissors.

```
print("  \t\t\t Welecome to Snake , Water , Gun game\n\n")


import random

attempts= 1
your_point=0
computer_point=0
while (attempts<=10):

    lst=["snake","water","gun"]
    ran=random.choice(lst)
    print("what do you choose snake, water or gun")
    inp=input()


    if inp==ran:
        print("tie")
        print(f"you choosed {inp} and computer guess is {ran}")
        print("No body gets point\n")



    elif inp=="snake" and ran=="water":
        your_point=your_point+1
        print(f"you choosed {inp} and computer guess is {ran}")
        print("The snake drank water\n")
        print("You won this round")
        print("you get 1 point\n")


    elif inp=="water" and ran=="snake":
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print(f"you choosed {inp} and computer guess is {ran}")
        print("The snake drank water\n")
        print("You Lost this round")
        print("computer gets 1 point\n")

    elif inp=="water" and ran=="gun":
        print(f"you choosed {inp} and computer guess is {ran}")
        your_point = your_point + 1
        print("The gun sank in water\n")
        print("You won this round")
        print("you get 1 point\n")


    elif inp == "gun" and ran == "water":
        print(f"you choosed {inp} and computer guess is {ran}")
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print("The gun sank in water\n")
        print("You Lost this round")
        print("computer gets 1 point\n")



    elif inp == "gun" and ran == "snake":
        print(f"you choosed {inp} and computer guess is {ran}")
        your_point = your_point + 1
        print("The snake was shoot and he died\n")
        print("You Won this round")
        print("you get 1 point\n")

    elif inp == "snake" and ran == "gun":
        print(f"you choosed {inp} and computer guess is {ran}")
        computer_point=computer_point+1
        print("The snake was shoot and he died\n")
        print("You Lost this round")
        print("computer gets 1 point\n")

    else:
        print("invalid")




    print(10 - attempts, "no. of guesses left")
    attempts = attempts + 1

    if attempts>10:
        print("game over")

if computer_point > your_point:
    print("Computer wins and you loose")

if computer_point < your_point:
    print("you win and computer loose")

print(f"your point is {your_point} and computer point is {computer_point}")
```